counting agents based on two conditions
I have a malaria model with humans, buildings, and mosquitoes. I want to capture the statistics of an infected human based on: 1. house type; 2. whether he/she is using a bed net. I managed to get statistics for elements used in the state chart, but for the details that are only in the database, I don't know how to go about it. my data contains user ID, bed-net use, house type, and infection status.
I have tried count(humans, h->h.h_type==A);
count(humans, h->h.h_benetuse==true);
May anyone please help me on how to get statistics on the infected human based on house type and based on whether the infected has been using bed-net or not?

Maybe consider creating a collection of humans that meet your condition, using a method like findAll(collection, condition)? Then, we could simply obtain the size of this collection using size(), indicating the actual count. While it may not be the most efficient approach, it seems like it should suffice for your problem!
